# Django if statement in DetailView returns False

Tags: django, if-statement, django-models, django-views, django-users

The main problem for me was: If a user is the owner of the prime then it should return **True**. But it always returns **False**.

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Prime(models.Model):
    prime_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    prime_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prime_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

My views.py:

```
class PrimeDetails(generic.DetailView):
    template_name ='prime/primedetails.html'
    model = Prime


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PrimeDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        prime_owner = Prime.prime_owner
        if user == prime_owner:
            owner = True
        else:
            owner = False
        context['owner'] = owner
        return context
```

primedetails.html

```
{% extends 'prime/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{ owner }}</h1>
    <h1>{{object.prime_name }}</h1>
    <h3>{{object.prime_address}}</h3>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prime is a model, not the object.
Try change the Prime to self.get_object(), like this:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PrimeDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        prime_owner = self.get_object().prime_owner
        if user == prime_owner:
            owner = True
        else:
            owner = False
        context['owner'] = owner
        return context
```

Comment: Yes exactly this is what i missed. thank you very much buddy

Comment: you are welcome :), if the answer solved the problem, please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I will but you answered so fast i still need 5 minutes till I can